# Долго выводиться текст на textEdit в qt через postgresql

Tags: c++, sql, qt, postgresql

Долго выводиться текст на textEdit в qt через postgresql.

```
int IndexOfID = model2->record(index.row()).value("ID").toInt();
```

Я выполняю запрос

```
myQueryOfIndex = QString ("SELECT ts_headline(\'russian_hunspell\', \"TextOfFile\", 
to_tsquery(\'russian_hunspell\',\'%1\'), \'StartSel =<b> , StopSel = </b>, HighlightAll=True\') 
as ttt FROM \"Table\" Where \"ID\" = %2 ").arg(A).arg(IndexOfID);
```

И использую, сопутствующий код:

```
    query.exec(myQueryOfIndex);

    int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf("ttt");

    if (query.next()) {
     QString text = query.value(fieldNo).toString();

   QString A = ui->lineEdit->text(); // Эту строку будем сравнивать с text

   int IndexPro = text.indexOf(A, Qt::CaseInsensitive); // Записываю IndexPro как индекс первого вхождения

      qDebug() << " Индекс вхождения равен: ";
      qDebug() << IndexPro; //Выводит: 0, если есть соответствие и -1 если его нет

      qDebug() << "Что именно соответствует:";
      qDebug() << A;

      text.remove(IndexPro, A.length()); //Удалить слово с позиции IndexPro, длиной А - слово введенное ранее

      QString HtmlCod = "<span style=\" font-size:8pt; font-weight:600;\">"+A+"</span>"; // HTML код форматирования

      QString NEW = text.insert(IndexPro, HtmlCod); //Вставить слово на позицию IndexPro, и что именно вставить
      qDebug() << NEW;
      //Вывод конечной строки в textEdit
      ui->textEdit->insertHtml(NEW);
```

Идея такова: я загружаю файлы в postgresql, выполняю запрос на выборку, у меня есть результат выборки - таблица в TableView, я нажимаю на ячейку и у меня в поле textEdit выводиться содержимое (оно выделено жирным) файла из ячейки в postgresql. Выборка происходит быстро, а вывод на textEdit долго, даже программа зависает, подскажите как можно это решить?

(При этом этот запрос в postgres выполняется 200 мс, и задействуется Seq scan)

Comment: к делу не относится, но значения стоит подставлять через `QSqlQuery::bindValue()`, а не `QString::arg()`... а по делу: «долго» — это сколько? о данных какого размера идёт речь? и какая именно операция всё же тормозит? ну и какова структура таблицы/какие индексы есть в базе? если тормозит запрос, то посмотри/покажи его план...

Comment: Одиночные кавычки в запросе экранировать бэкслэшем не нужно.